# Aggregate one column based on the date range in R

Tags: r, merge

I Have two data frames, df1 and df2:

```
# first 15 rows
df1 <- data.frame(
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         patient_id = c("54c00a685cd49f4ed59a389657af655b","a135b44a73f9e99424a91edc846185de",
                        "4a8da205ade786dd74c316c39dcbe99f",
                        "277ad90d43a1289b0bf22f9795c5c706","a54070aa18ab3579495a157364f70a39",
                        "a55c86b62d1da4c513682a54d83fb8f4","acb38a4b08557944f979980df5a66b3c",
                        "0eacfb2daed1f3ba2adf32e293bc05a6",
                        "51bec2147575bb6160061904c360acb4","a35104169c15196530d2e21f79638f47",
                        "4d2f19debc7312f0013d17fff3876568",
                        "c7437fdd4e183fa19ca2a6df1ede154c","e5ab3d5d148d3fe05b02e395bdd47399",
                        "47120b709b346a084e7cc0ffd5e35e1a",
                        "e7066216951034ed737e5883b52e9bcf"),
  date_of_admission = c("2013-02-23","2013-11-28",
                        "2014-12-12","2012-02-16","2012-12-03","2012-10-28",
                        "2015-08-25","2014-01-28","2013-08-14","2014-05-06",
                        "2013-03-18","2011-01-27","2013-06-19","2011-12-25",
                        "2014-12-02"),
             amount = c(6539.15929958,876.424366181,
                        956.96893313,836.612493288,397.293040648,
                        20680.1290122,1090.15406859,14383.3646206,16733.2105492,
                        826.458041597,1598.69349542,1854.45957087,2381.80183936,
                        1362.86947894,1260.23011573)
)

# first 15 rows
df2 <- data.frame(
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 id = c("1d21f2be18683991eb93d182d6b2d220","62bdca0b95d97e99e1c712048fb9fd09",
                        "c85cf97bc6307ded0dd4fef8bad2fa09",
                        "e0397dd72caf4552c5babebd3d61736c","94ade3cd5f66f4584902554dff170a29",
                        "59e07adc2dbc5f70131f57d003610d74","f5c4d97ebf32d49967fbf4f6c5fd52ec",
                        "1e788744568c21b390c5aa8c5dd61335",
                        "457402b26562d41f4e40906d3d17d5d1","79f52395dab0e6d3a03c48f765cb6562",
                        "d45fcf3bec63ae3b436be42fad33b9e0",
                        "e83f56a339b8a09e87128aa34a7c5a37","35ec0e9e49240db8e864abb3b9b536fa",
                        "7f8e1a194c89076622a7f99cd835e170",
                        "c59af905597b9be72420bbdbdad2ce42"),
  date_of_admission = c("2011-01-01","2011-01-01",
                        "2011-01-02","2011-01-02","2011-01-08","2011-01-07",
                        "2011-01-06","2011-01-07","2011-01-12","2011-01-02",
                        "2011-01-12","2011-01-09","2011-01-11","2011-01-14",
                        "2011-01-10"),
  date_of_discharge = c("2011-01-11","2011-01-11",
                        "2011-01-13","2011-01-14","2011-01-16","2011-01-17",
                        "2011-01-17","2011-01-17","2011-01-18","2011-01-18",
                        "2011-01-18","2011-01-20","2011-01-22","2011-01-22",
                        "2011-01-22")
)
```

The rest of the data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d-zjCSGpN2PGLoahKEmm-WddCad6wWVs).

What I need (df3) is: for each unique patient id, if the date of admission in df1 lies between the date_of_admission & date of discharge of df2, then sum the amount in df1.

So I want output DF3 as given below:

[image]

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use `dput` on both dataframes and post the results in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# import and tidy the datasets
df1 <-  read_csv("df1.csv") %>%
            select(patient_id, date_of_admission, amount) %>%
            group_by(patient_id, date_of_admission) %>%
            summarise(amount = sum(amount)) # sum the amount for each patient_id and date interval


df2 <-  read_csv("df2.csv") %>%
            select(patient_id = id, start = date_of_admission, end = date_of_discharge)
 
df2 %>%
    left_join (df1, by = c("patient_id"), relationship = "many-to-many") %>% # join the dataframes
    filter(start <= date_of_admission & date_of_admission <= end) %>%
    group_by(patient_id, start, end) %>%
    summarise(total_amount = sum(amount))

   patient_id                       start      end        total_amount
   <chr>                            <date>     <date>            <dbl>
 1 00225710a878eff524a1d13be817e8e2 2014-04-10 2014-04-22        5191.
 2 0029d90eb654699c18001c17efb0f129 2012-11-07 2012-11-20       22601.
 3 0040333abd68527ecb53e1db9073f52e 2013-01-19 2013-01-31       17447.
 4 00473b58e3dc8ae37b3cb34069705083 2014-02-10 2014-02-15       15286.
 5 0078662d1d983dde68ea057c42d5b5cf 2012-04-28 2012-05-10       73478.
 6 0088bbd94c90bbc9158e13465441ebb6 2015-11-05 2015-11-15       26052.
 7 0092d20dd0719e88ecfdd02d5e7ca7b7 2013-01-20 2013-01-31       21499.
 8 01081b8bcb0f9e27b888d23bb35a50dd 2011-02-02 2011-02-12       27512.
 9 010cf28233f50d3857b499a9c208c610 2011-02-03 2011-02-11       25612.
10 0116c5d9b6c2c2e8758c75e6da86014b 2012-09-01 2012-09-10       15791.
# ℹ 3,390 more rows
```

Comment: It is give me error .                     clinical_data %>%
+   mutate(total = sum(df1$amount[between(df1$date_of_admission, date_of_admission, date_of_discharge) & df1$patient_id == patient_id]))
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `total = sum(...)`.
Caused by error in `between()`:
! `left` must be length 1
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
>

Comment: post the data then?

Comment: Here is the link to the data .https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d-zjCSGpN2PGLoahKEmm-WddCad6wWVs

Comment: Hope you are able to access the data ?

Comment: I was able to! Thank you brother!

Comment: My old approach was too clever by half, so I switched to a traditional join and filter

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small function like this.

```
f <- \(df1, df2) {
  Map(\(x, y) {
    apply(y, 1, \(z) {
      s <- subset(x, date >= z[2] & date <= z[ 3])
      cbind(t(z), data.frame(total=sum(s$amount), n=nrow(s)))
    }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  }, split(df1, df1$id), split(df2, df2$id)) |> do.call(what='rbind')
}

f(df1, df2)
#     id     date_a     date_d    total n
# 1.1  1 2020-10-01 2023-06-27 21162.39 4
# 1.2  1 2023-06-28 2023-06-29 24631.33 4
# 2.3  2 2021-07-28 2021-07-30 10586.23 2
# 2.4  2 2022-12-10 2022-12-15  8694.92 2
```

Of course, you have to adapt the variable names to your data. According to your comment, you need:

```
f <- \(df1, df2) {
  Map(\(x, y) {
    apply(y, 1, \(z) {
      s <- subset(x, date_of_admission >= z['date_of_admission'] & date_of_admission <= z['date_of_discharge'])
      cbind(t(z[
        c("id", "date_of_admission", "date_of_discharge")
      ]), data.frame(total=sum(s$amount), n=nrow(s)))
    }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
  }, split(df1, df1$patient_id), split(df2, df2$id)) |> do.call(what='rbind')
}
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), amount = c(8318.45, 
8496.6, 3289.12, 7643.58, 6133.96, 5152.77, 6892.71, 2077.33, 
6255.94, 6640.52, 4661.93, 6752.9), date = structure(c(18536, 
18536, 19536, 19536, 19536, 19536, 18536, 18536, 18836, 18836, 
19336, 19336), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), date_a = c("2020-10-01", "2023-06-28", 
"2021-07-28", "2022-12-10"), date_d = c("2023-06-27", "2023-06-29", 
"2021-07-30", "2022-12-15")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: I am getting the below error while running the above function .                                        Error in date >= z[2] : 
comparison (>=) is possible only for atomic and list types

Comment: @PraveenChougale It works fine with example data. Analyze what's the difference to your data. Use e.g. `str(df1)`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error . I am Sharron’s the data for your reference. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1d-zjCSGpN2PGLoahKEmm-WddCad6wWVs